# SVM Scores - Upper Bound?

Tags: machine-learning, svm

I have a concern about support vector machines, namely their classification scores:
Do these classification scores have an upper bound?
I think no, since an SVM is just a hyperplane, and the score basically a point's distance to that hyperplane. Without restrictions, a point could lie anywhere in the space and thus the distance does not have any bound, does it?

I am asking, because I have read the following line:

> "When decision scores are bounded — and SVM scores are bounded by the margin — ..."

Could you explain what is meant by that? I don't see how the margin is a bound on the detection score...

Thanks for your help, I appreciate it!

Comment: Yes. This is one of the many reasons why I prefer Bayesian approaches that spit out probabilities.

Comment: What do probabilities have to do with this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your intuition is correct. Whatever you read is misleading at best or plain wrong (some context is required in any case). SVM decision values do not have an upper bound. It depends entirely on the test instances.

SVM decision values are a linear combination of inner products in feature space of the test instance and the support vectors. If the test instance has infinite norm, these inner products will be infinite as well.